# How can we open raddatepicker popup window up the Radwindow popup

Tags: asp.net, telerik, raddatepicker

I have raddatepicker control in radwindow.The size of radwindow is fixed. when i open the raddatepicker popup it shows scroll bar in radwindow due to less space.

I don't want to show the scroll bar. so my question is **Can we open the datepicker popup upon the radwindow**.

[image: scroll bar when datepicker popup is open]

Answer (score 1):

Use the ContentTemplate of the RadWindow to have all controls inside on the same page, instead of in an iframe: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/contenttemplatevsnavigateurl/defaultcs.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

`RadDatePicker` has `PopupDirection` property. You can use `TopLeft` to popup top instead of bottom.

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="RadDatePicker1" PopupDirection="TopLeft">
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

- TopLeft
- TopRight
- BottomLeft
- BottomRight (Default)

Comment: i tried this, but it din't solve the problem. Now upper part of the calendar hides.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit scroll bars by changing the position of the RadDatePicker popup.

[The solution I found here.](http://www.telerik.com/forums/popup-position-for-raddatepicker)

.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    RadDatePicker1.DatePopupButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "PopupAbove(event, '" + RadDatePicker1.ClientID + "');return false;"); 
}
```

.aspx

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" Runat="server"> 
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

.aspx JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function PopupAbove(e, pickerID) 
{ 
    var datePicker; 
    if (pickerID == null) 
    { 
        datePicker = $find("<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        datePicker = $find(pickerID); 
    }     
    var textBox = datePicker.get_textBox(); 
    var popupElement = datePicker.get_popupContainer();     
    var dimensions = datePicker.getElementDimensions(popupElement); 
    var position = datePicker.getElementPosition(textBox);     
    datePicker.showPopup(position.x, position.y - dimensions.height);     
} 
</script>
```

You can popup position by changing `datePicker.showPopup(width,height);`

ex.

```
datePicker.showPopup(position.x-100, position.y - 100);
```